# Sidebaroverlapping the Div created in content place holder, how can i prevent it?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, xhtml

i made a sidebar template in ASP .NET. when I click on button X on the left top corner, the sidebar on the left appear. The sidebar is made in the Master page. I used this master page in other pages, I've made a div on a page . The problem is its appearing over the sidebar not under the sidebar. Any how i can get it under the sidebar ?

here's link to the image of the template

http://ge.tt/7bGLHnu1/v/0?c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help without any code.

Have you tried to set different values of z-index?

it could look like this:

```
#div{ z-index: 100;}
```

Comment: yeah , i tried .. not working. i can give you code .. which module code do you want ?

Comment: please show a live-version or an example via [link](http://jsfiddle.net/) , then i'll be able to see your problem and probably solve it.

Comment: i solved it, i just selected the module in design view Visual Studio and then clicked on format , then from there i sent the div back of the slidbar. thanks for the help